# Scatter plot a dictionary containing an array as value using matplotlib

Tags: python

I have a dictionary containing a unique ID (DNA-Sequence Id's in this case) as a key with an array of floats (weight data)  as corresponding values eg:

```
{"Seq_1": {222.1,225.4,228.4}, "Seq_2": {113.2,118,119.0,140,8,}, ....}
```

Some Id's may have more data than others so  The length of the values array is not always equal.

I need to (scatter) plot this dictionary. The ID's should be on the X-axis as text with their corresponding weights on the Y-axes.

Somewhat like the image below:

[Example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNffV.png)

I managed to create the image above with this code:

```
key_array = plot_dict.keys()
key_array_all_ID = []
values_array_MW = []

for key in key_array :
        for value in plot_dict.get(key):
            key_array_all_ID.append(key)
            values_array_MW.append(value)
            
u, indices = np.unique(key_array_all_ID, return_inverse = True)
plt.scatter(indices, values_array_MW)
plt.xticks(range(len(u)), u, rotation = 90)
plt.show()
```

For some reason I think this might be done much more efficient. Since now, i'm destructuring the dictionary completely.

Any Suggestions on this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a slight improvement:

```
for key, values in dic.items():
    key_array_all_ID += [key] * len(values)
    values_array_MW += values
```

But i don't think you need to search any further, not everything can and needs to be a oneliner!

Comment: Completely agree... Thanks alot for helping me out.

Comment: Could you perhaps accept the answer?